# ScalaTest: customized value output for predefined type

Tags: scala, scalatest

Say, I have trivial test like this:

```
class Test extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("test") {
    val array = Array(
      Array(1, 1, 1),
      Array(2, 1, 3),
      Array(1, 4, 1)
    )

    array should equal (null)
  }

}
```

... that fails as:

```
Array(Array(1, 1, 1), Array(2, 1, 3), Array(1, 4, 1)) did not equal null
```

My `array` represents game field, and I'd like it to be printed in test output similar to:

```
1 1 1
2 1 3
1 4 1
```

... instead of:

```
Array(Array(1, 1, 1), Array(2, 1, 3), Array(1, 4, 1))
```

Is there a way to do this in ScalaTest?

Comment: Use a `class GameField(field: Array[Array[Int]]) { override def toString = ... }` instead of using the nested array directly.

Comment: @sschaef thanks for suggestion, but this is not an option for me. Wrapping field array is a complication I do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to use is WithClue. Something like this

```
val a = Array( Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6),Array(7,8,9))
def p (x:Array[Array[Int]]) = x.foreach( x=> {x.foreach(print);println;} )
withClue(p(a) ) {a should equal (null)}
```

Between I think you would be looking for overriding the matcher. As I see you will be next comparing Array*Array to Array*Array, and may be you will looking for very specific comparison where the comparisons are failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.
You might consider using an additional class and companion object to wrap the array right before the `should`. Class and companion must be such they do not invalidate your `null` test but provide a prettier print. For instance:

```
class ArrayPrettyPrinter(array : Array[Int]) {
   override def toString() : String = {
      // your pretty print implementation here
   }
}

object ArrayPrettyPrinter {
   def apply(array : Array[Int]) : ArrayPrettyPrinter = {
      if (array == null) return null
      return new ArrayPrettyPrinter(array)
   }
}
```

And your test should become:

```
class Test extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("test") {
    val array = Array(
      Array(1, 1, 1),
      Array(2, 1, 3),
      Array(1, 4, 1)
    )

    ArrayPrettyPrinter(array) should equal (null)
  }    
}
```